# What causes a correctly sized circuit breaker to trip?

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits, current

I have a suicide shower head and even though the breaker is correctly sized it trips after about 6-8 minutes of showering.

Comment: To answer the question "what in @#$% is a 'suicide shower head'": https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112085/how-suicidal-are-electric-suicide-showers

Comment: This may be a much better fit for diy.stackexchange.com.  That's a home-improvement site, and if there's any plumbers or electricians from countries where these things are used, they may have a lot more insight into the actual practical "why" of it.

Comment: Perhaps the "suicide" shower head is faulty.

Comment: Correctly sized how?  Is the wire sized correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Circuit breakers trip because the current is too high or because they are faulty.

A clip-on ammeter will tell you which problem you have.

High amps could be a faulty heater, a partial short-circuit, or possibly too-small wires (you are heating up the wires).

Comment: Note: When the current is too high, or the breaker is faulty, "6-8 minutes" is normal behavior. Breaker design and specification includes provision to open after they heat up -- which may be 10 minutes, depending on how big the overload is.

Comment: Circuit breakers do not detect wire heating. The circuit breaker's amperage is selected so that it trips before the wire gets too hot.

Comment: @user253751 hot wire draw more amps

Comment: @TigerGuy Other way around. Wires with more amps get hot.

Comment: @user253751 oaky, but an overloaded (undersize) wire will draw more amps.

Comment: @TigerGuy does a car that is pulled over by a police officer go fast?

Comment: @TigerGuy, it's the load that determines the amps, not the wire gauge. If anything an overloaded wire will cause an increased voltage drop along the wire and reduced voltage at the load and the current drawn will decrease as a result (but this is not the case for constant power loads). Have you started the New Year celibrations early?